# Java Proguard Unresolved classes Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, proguard

Proguard isn't able to obfuscate my .jar file. I'm using IntelliJ and Maven

It throws a lot of notices '[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class'

and a lot of warnings including:

'Warning: org.jboss.netty.example.localtime.LocalTimeProtocol$LocalTimes$Builder: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite'

```
 [proguard] Note: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory accesses a declared field 'handler' dynamically
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'javassist.bytecode.analysis.Analyzer$ExceptionInfo { int handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory { javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'javassist.util.proxy.SerializedProxy { javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext { org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline$StaticChannelHandlerContext { org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingClientSocketChannel { org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingClientSocketChannel$ServletChannelHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is library field 'javax.xml.ws.spi.http.HttpContext { javax.xml.ws.spi.http.HttpHandler handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is library field 'sun.applet.AppletPanel { java.lang.Thread handler; }'
 [proguard]       Maybe this is library field 'sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection { sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler handler; }'
 [proguard] Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
 [proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
 [proguard] Warning: there were 874 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard] Note: there were 5 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
 [proguard]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
 [proguard]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
 [proguard]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
 [proguard]       You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
 [proguard]       their implementations (using '-keep').
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
 [proguard] Warning: there were 65 unresolved references to program class members.
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
 [proguard] Note: there were 10 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
 [proguard]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
 [proguard]       (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
 [proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
 [proguard]          You may need to recompile the code.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
 [proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

My pom:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.eu.habbo.Emulator</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>4.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>4.10</proguardVersion>
                    <options>
                        <option>-keep public class myapp.Main{public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                        <lib>C:\Users\wesley\.m2\repository\org\jboss\netty\netty\3.2.0.Final\netty-3.2.0.Final.jar</lib>
                        <lib>C:\Users\wesley\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.31\mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar</lib>
                        <lib>C:\Users\wesley\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.7\slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar</lib>
                        <lib>C:\Users\wesley\.m2\repository\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar</lib>
                        <lib>C:\Users\wesley\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\1.4.0\HikariCP-1.4.0.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have to obfuscate this .JAR. I can't find any other alternatives for Maven projects. I found yGuard but that is for ant.